# Can I JBT compile code on Windows RT and Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, jit, windows-rt

I have done a bit of reading into JIT compiling code because I want to port and emulator to Windows Phone 8 and Windows RT but I have noticed that Microsoft has disallowed the VirtualProtect() and related APIs neccessary to execute a block of memory containing compiled code. I therefor thought it might be possible to compile the code before it needs to be launched and save it to storage. My question is though, would it be possible to execute external code on storage and if not, would it be possible for the program to expand itself with the new binaries that would then be executable on the next launch.

If the above won't work is there any way I can compile code on the device and the be able to execute it.

Also I am struggling to find reading material on the matter so if you do not have an answer to this could you atleast rever me to some relevant reading material.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you are after is possible but check out Microsoft's TouchDevelop (if you haven't done so already).  It allows you to create apps, via scripts, that can run on pretty much any of your devices (Windows Phones, PC, iPad, iPhone, Android, & Mac).  I don't know if you can directly incorporate this into your apps or not but it may give you some ideas.

1. [Microsoft Research Page for TouchDevelop](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/touchdevelop/)
2. [Main Web Site](https://www.touchdevelop.com/)
3. [In the Windows Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/touchdevelop/fe08ccec-a360-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8)

Comment: Sorry, I have looked at it but it basically just a scripting language and cannot help me with my problem.

Comment: Ok.  Just wanted to throw it out there in case it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the XDA-DEVELOPERS forum. I found this.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2594420

Comment: This isn't directly what I am looking for but it might help